# JQuery select in dialog does not have options appended

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

I am trying to use a JQuery dialog to act similar to an open file dialog, but instead of files I am using records from a database to populate the dialog.

The problem that I am having is that I cannot seem to get the html option data loaded into the html select in my dialog. I have used the Google Javascript debugger in Chrome and have stepped through my javascript code which is called from my PHP ajax. I see no errors and I see the data is there and formatted correctly when I put it into the append statement.  I don't understand why it does not show up in my html select.

Thanks for your help.

below is my Ajax function which receives the data.

function doOpenAjax(filterStr) 
    {

```
    $.get(
        "contenteditServerAjax.php",
        {filter: filterStr },
        function(data) {
                            var optsArr = data.split('|~|');
                            var seloption = "";

                            $.each(optsArr, function(i) {
                                seloption += '<option value="' + optsArr[i] + '">' + optsArr[i] + '</option>';
                            });
                            $('#chooseArticleName2').find('option').remove().end();
                            $('#chooseArticleName2').append(seloption);
                        },
        "html"
        );

}
```

For reference this is part of my php which contains the jquery dialog:

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dlg = $("#opendiv").dialog({modal:true, height:550, width:650,
                        hide:{ effect: 'drop', direction: "down" },
                        autoOpen:false,
                        maxHeight: 1200,
                        maxWidth: 1200,  
                        minHeight: 250,
                        minWidth: 300, 
                        buttons: { "Open": function() { $('#state').val('Open Doc');        $('#contentform').submit(); $(this).dialog("hide"); },
                        "Cancel": function() { $(this).dialog("close");}}                            
    });
    dlg.parent().appendTo($("#contentform"));  

});
</script>
```

```
<div id="opendiv" name="opendiv" title="OPEN">

    <p align="center">Enter Name to Open Article as:</p>
    <p>
        Filter:
        <input name="docFilter2" id="docFilter2" type="text" value="$filter2" maxlen="64" size="28"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input name="LoadTitles2" id="LoadTitles2" type="button" value="Load Available Titles" 
                                onclick="doOpenAjax( $('#docFilter2').val() );"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <div id="ajaxOutput2">
            <select name="chooseArticleName2" id="list2" size="8" style="min-width:92%"
                                        onchange="
                                        var mytext = $('#chooseArticleName2 :selected').text();
                                        $('#textBoxArticleName2').val(mytext);">
            </select>
        </div>
    </p>
    <p>
        Document:
        <input type="text" id="textBoxArticleName2" name="textBoxArticleName2" size="56"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, it would be more efficient to do this:

```
$('#chooseArticleName2').empty().html(seloption);
```

Than this:

```
$('#chooseArticleName2').find('option').remove().end();
$('#chooseArticleName2').append(seloption);
```

Comment: Thanks jack, originally I was doing something similar where I was returning the html from the ajax php and replacing the entire div.  The reason that I dropped that approach was that I was having issues with the onchange callback from the $('#chooseArticleName2') select control when I replaced the html which I believe also would replace the onchange callback.